# Is Henry the Vampire from a previous show?

Tags: being-human-us

In Being Human, they introduced Henry Fitzroy and I remember him being from a previous show called Blood Ties (on the Lifetime network in the US).

Are these the same character? If so, does that mean the two shows shared a universe?

Comment: The US or UK version?

Comment: The US version.

Comment: Quite a common name through history, it seems - wouldn't be surprised if multiple shows used him as a vampire:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Fitzroy

Answer (score 2):

I don't see Henry Fitzroy listed as a character on imdb for Being Human, and comparing the creators, producers, and writers for both shows, I don't see any overlap, so I doubt they are related. More likely they are both referencing some common person in history or literature, possibly one of the people Izkata pointed to.

Comment: on Sci-Fi's Being Human remake there is a "Henry" listed:  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1595680/fullcredits#cast

Comment: I don't see why this was voted down. Is anything I said disputed? The point I'm making is that it's unlikely that there is a connection given no crew in common.

Comment: Nor do I see why, +1 to offset it..

Answer (score 0):

Kyle is the same actor playing both but not the same character. Henry on Being Human is too
young to be Henry Fitzoy.

Answer (score -1):

When I first saw the episode introducing Henry on Being Human, I was like "Hey, isn't that.....?" Looked it up and it was indeed the same actor playing a vamp named Henry, again! I don't know if he is supposed to be Henry Fitzroy with a bit of a different storyline or if it is just an homage to Blood Ties. Either way, dang!...he lookin' good!
Also that nurse that reincarnates ghost, Zoe, looks a lot like the young nurse Zoe on Nurse Jackie, another homage?